# Are there non-triangle Fuchsian groups?

Tags: group-theory

The only Fuchsian groups I know of (apart from silly ones like finite cyclic groups) are the subgroups of triangle groups. For instance, the modular group $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

I've only ever seen [hard-to-construct examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109688/fuchsian-groups-and-triangle-groups/109690) of others.

1. Can anyone give some easier-to-construct examples?
2. Is there some sort of classification of Fuchsian groups, or of a large subclass of them?

There must exist a lot since, as the link says, almost all Fuchsian groups are non-triangular.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of easy to construct examples of [*Arithmetic Fuchsian Groups*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_Fuchsian_group); see also the book of Svetlana Katok on Fuchsian groups. All arithmetic triangle Fuchsian groups are classified, see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1240433796). So it easy to find new examples.